# Simulating a Button click using its type with javascript not its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I am trying to automate a website test using JavaScript. Part of my tests include clicking a button that has a `type`, but no `id`.

I've tried to do this using a jQuery code that I found online but it didn't work. Is there any way to simulate the click using the `type` of the button?

This is the HTML of the button I am trying to target:

```
<button type="submit">Go</button>
```

Comment: People can't hep you very well if you don't show us the code you're working with

Comment: Please do not repeat text, there is no valid reason for it.

Comment: "<button type="submit">Go</button>" am trying to stimulate the click on that button

Comment: $('button[type="submit"]') should select that

Comment: You can use a type attribute as a selector in finding the button ie `jQuery('[type="button"]')` as for simulating the click and triggering an event listener you would use jQuery's `trigger()` method. But if that didn't work you need to explain exactly you want to happen when that button is clicked, eg event handler trigger vs something like default form submission from button click

Comment: it worked thank u i added $('button[type="submit"]').click();  the .click() and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery attribute selector, `$(element[attribute='value'])`

```
$('button[type="submit"]')
```

You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) if you want to understand more of the selector - you can do things such as select based on the start / end of an attribute, or if it is *not* the value you give